# How to print or list __stdcall decorated C functions in gdb

Tags: c, gdb, mingw

Consider following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void __stdcall foo(int bar)
{
    printf("bar is %d", bar);
}

int main()
{
    foo(42);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with i686-w64-mingw32-gcc as follows:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -g    stdcall.c   -o stdcall
```

Then start gdb:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gdb stdcall
```

and list functions (only showing functions of stdcall.c):

```
(gdb) info function
[...]
File stdcall.c:
void foo@4(int);
int main();
```

As you can see the foo function gets decorated (which is
expected).

How do I print the address of this function or list it? I
tried:

```
(gdb) p foo
No symbol "foo" in current context.
(gdb) p foo@4
No symbol "foo" in current context.
(gdb) p _foo@4
No symbol "_foo" in current context.
(gdb) p _foo
No symbol "_foo" in current context.
```

whereas main is found:

```
(gdb) p main
$1 = {int ()} 0x40154e <main>
```

similar for the list command:

```
(gdb) list _foo@4
Function "_foo@4" not defined.
[and so on ...]
```

How do I address the foo function in gdb when it is
decorated? I assume it is something very simple but
I can't find it right now.

The gdb version is:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gdb stdcall
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=i686-w64-mingw32".
```

The compiler version is:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc --version
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 7.3-win32 20180312
```

Thanks for ideas :)

Comment: Try `p 'foo@4'`.

Comment: Thank you @ssbssa exactly the single quotes did the trick ... I never would have thought of that. Do you want to write an answer or should I?

Answer (score 0):

As @ssbssa pointed out the solution is to use single quotes as in:

```
p 'foo@4'
```